# Excel not opening .csv files

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I reorganised my folders in Windows Explorer and when I try to open some .csv files with excel I get an error "Sorry we couldn't find "xyz.csv". Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?" However the file is there and I can open the file with Notepad++. Does anyone understand what's going on? Is there a way to resolve the issue so I can open them with excel? Many thanks

Comment: Are you double-clicking the file from Windows Explorer, or using the most recent files list in Excel?

Comment: Double-clicking in Windows Explorer. I haven't opened the file before. Same error when I try to open from within excel

Comment: When you open the file with Notepad++, are there any weird extra characters before/after the content of the file? Or an unexpected file header/footer?

Comment: No, nothing odd. I can copy & paste the file into excel and work with it that way, just curious what's going on, and it would be easier to open the file directly in excel. The csv file is output from a NetLogo experiment in BehaviourSpace, if that's of relevance?

Comment: No. CSV is CSV, is CSV...

Comment: If you open it in Notepad++, what does it say the encoding is? UTF-8? Are there any special/reserved characters in the content?

Comment: Yes, it's UTF-8 and no special characters, just numbers, text, commas, "CR", "LF". Exactly the data I'd expect and when I copy and place into excel, all as expected.

Comment: You can search the file name in file explorer search bar.

Comment: I've gotten that error message when the folder path or file name of the Excel file is too long.  Try copying the file to a folder like C:\Temp and see if it opens.

Comment: Thanks Randy, yes moving it to C:\Temp worked and now the .csv file opens in Excel.